# Calling Create PDF method in iphone application  nor working

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview

I want to creat the pdf from the view i am using following code i have got this from the web but how to call this method and where to give the file name for creating the pdf which is saved in documents folder.

When i call this method it gives exception unrecognized selector sent.

```
  [self createPDFfromUIView:someView saveToDcumentsWithFileName:@"my_pdf.pdf"];



 -(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename


{
// Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

// Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


// draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

[aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

// remove PDF rendering context
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

// Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

// instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
[pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
 }
```

Comment: If you read carefully method names provide you everythin. e.g createPDFfromUIView which will take UIview object from which you want to create PDF and saveToDocumentsWithFileName which tells you, pass the name of pdf file which you want. This file will be created in Document directory.

Comment: I am doing in this way gives exception when i call this method say unrecognized selector sent

Comment: @EXC_BAD_ACCESS please how i am calling method is it correct or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working code....Dont forget to add QuartzCore.h

```
 #include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];


     [self createPDFfromUIView:self.view saveToDocumentsWithFileName:@"abc.pdf"];

  }
  -(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:    (NSString*)aFilename


  {
     // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

// Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


// draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData


[aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

// remove PDF rendering context
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

// Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

// instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
[pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you have that method implemented in a class, and were calling it from the same class. You would do it like so:

```
[self createPDFfromUIView:someView saveToDcumentsWithFileName:@"my_pdf.pdf"];
```

This will save your `UIView` as a PDF in your `Documents` directory with a filename of, `my_pdf.pdf`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: calling this way gives exception terminationg app due to unrecognised selector sent to line which you have written

Comment: i think we need do create the file first

Comment: You have to put that method in your class `@implementation`. unrecognized selector means you aren't calling it from the right place.

Comment: i am putting this in implementation and i am calling this in view didload method

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GraphsViewController createPDFfromUIView:saveToDcumentsWithFileName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6edd1d0'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: probelem is not calling in viewDidLoad i am calling now on button click but again same probelm

Comment: I don't care what method you use, I just want to see how it is you're calling it. That error only means 1 thing, and nothing else. The method you're calling is not in the class.

Comment: -(IBAction)savePDF{ [self createPDFfromUIView:self.view saveToDcumentsWithFileName:@"my_pdf.pdf"];}